# Ticketing System Logic

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently we have a ticket management system and like all ticketing systems it needs to assign cases in a round-robin manner to the agents. Also, at the same time the agent can apply their own filtering logic and work on their queue.

The problem,

1. The table with the tickets is very large now, spans over 10 million rows.
2. One ticket should never be assigned to two different users.
3. To solve the above problem, this is the flow we have,
4. Select query is fired with filter criteria and limit 0,1
5. The row returned by the above query is then selected based on id and locked for update.
6. Lastly we fire the update saying user X has picked the case.
7. While step 3 executes other user cannot get a lock on the same case, so they fire 3.a query may be multiple times to get the next available case.
8. As number of users increase this time in step 4 goes higher and higher.

We tried doing a select for update in query at step 4 itself, but it makes the entire query slow. Assuming this is because a huge number of rows in the select query.

Questions,

- Is there a different approach we need to take altogether?
- Would doing a select and update in a stored procedure ensure the same results as doing a select for update and then update?

Comment: Why not make the assignee be a column on the ticket table?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach the problem like this:

1. Update the first open ticket to be handled by user USERID:

   `UPDATE tickets SET processedby=USERID WHERE processedby = (SELECT id FROM tickets WHERE processedby=NULL LIMIT 0,1)`
2. Get the ticket

   `SELECT * FROM tickets WHERE processedby=USERID`
3. Update the ticket after it has been processed.

Comment: Limit doesn't work in sub query.